# Prolog - How to replace certain words in a list

Tags: prolog

I have the following prolog predicate:

```
processWords([hello, my, name, is, Simon], Result).
```

I need to know how I could get:

```
Result = [bye, my, name, is, Ben]
```

How would I recurse through the list and return a string that replaces "hello" with "bye" and "Simon" with "Ben", using Prolog?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this cannot be done, since "Simon" and "Ben" in your example are variables. But supposing you are fine with "simon" and "ben", here is an answer:

```
processWords([], []).

processWords([H|T], [H2|T2]) :-
    translate(H, H2),
    processWords(T, T2).

translate(hello, bye):-!.
translate(simon, ben):-!.
translate(X, X). % catch-all clause for all words not to be translated
```

Alternatively, you could use `maplist/3`:

```
processWords(L,L2):-maplist(translate, L, L2).

translate(hello, bye):- !.
translate(simon, ben):- !.
translate(X, X). % catch-all clause for all words not to be translated
```

Comment: `processWords([hello],[hello])` incorrectly succeeds

Comment: you are right that your example suceeds. The question is whether the definition is incorrect. I assumed to define a predicate processWord(+List, -List). If you want other usages, you need to modify translate/2, of course.

Comment: Mmmh, isn't that a normal phenomenen in Prolog that expecially when using the cut, it normally matters which arguments are instantiated and which not? It can easily be changed such that it also works for processWord(+List,+NewList). Then it is not as pretty any more. Why would one do it if it is only used for processWord(+List,-NewList)?

Comment: But, please, feel free to post qour own answer. And make sure that it also works for the case that both arguments are uninstantiated, because ..., well, just because.

Comment: Please do study the notion of steadfastness.

Comment: Please do give an argument why the predicate has to be steadfast.