# list processing in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and I'm having trouble with this problem. I am taking a sentence as input and put [Anne,do,you,know] in front of the sentence and replace any occurrence of you to I.

For example copycat([you,love,me], X) will return X = [Anne,do,you,know,i,love,you].

```
copycat([],[]).
copycat([Head|Tail],[Head|TailX]):-
    Head :=: you,
    TailX is [Anne,do,you,know,i]+Tail,
    copycat(Tail, TailX).
```

Here is what I have been working on, and it's giving me false.

Comment: what prolog system do you use? what operator is ':=:'?

Comment: do you also want to replace me to you?

Comment: @tiffi i use swi-prolog and no i think just replace you to I.

Comment: in your example, you also replace me with you.

Comment: What happens if you ask ?- X :=: 1 Do you use any libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to break this in two parts, since you want to replace **every** suitable element of the list by something, but you only want to add [Anne, do,you,know] **once**.

So you could define your predicate like this:

```
copycat(In, [anne,do,you,know|Intermediate]):-
     translate(In, Intermediate).
```

You can try this with temporarily adding `translate(L,L).`, which does not alter the list.

`Anne` is a variable, so I changed it to `anne`, which is an atom.

As for the second part of your problem: you say you want to

> replace any occurrence of you to I.

But in your example you also replace me by you:

> For example copycat([you,love,me], X) will return X =
> [Anne,do,you,know,i,love,you].

There is already an answered question on the translation part:

[Prolog - How to replace certain words in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514010/prolog-how-to-replace-certain-words-in-a-list)

Comment: I'm stuck with the appending part `copycat([H|T], ResultList):-translate(H, IH), copycat(T, IT), append([Anne,do,you,know,IH],IT,ResultList).`

Comment: It is giving me `X = [what,makes,you,say,i,what,makes,you,say,like,what,makes,you,say,you].`

Comment: As I told you - it makes no sense to do the appending part in the recursion, since you want to append only **once**.